# Pcap to arff conversion?

Tags: weka, wireshark, pcap, arff

I wanted to know if there's a way to convert pcap files into arff files so that they can be inputted and used by weka? I am currently working on internet traffic analysis and the only way i can collect data is through coralreef and wireshark. Though helpful they do not have a feature that helps me with this conversion. So is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to convert pcap to csv file format using wireshark. you can go to option and then export packet dissection in csv. It is readable in weka with features.
 secondly you can use netmate a linux plateform based softare to convert pcap in arff file.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to convert pcap file to arff using netmate in Ubuntu.I used the following command " netmate -r /rulefiles/netAI-rules-stats-ni.xml -f Facebook.pcap ". But the output file seems empty, what I'm I missing here. Isn't this the correct usage.Please help

Answer (score -2):

The ARFF format is used to describe features, while pcap is used to describe packets. There is no magic way to turn packets into features, you have to know what features you want and extract them.

Comment: Provided i do know the attributes i need , what then? How do i proceed?

Comment: You can process pcap files with perl, python, java.. and then extract the features you want. All of these languages have also libraries for writing ARFF files.

Comment: Can you provide links that might help me learn how to select and extract features from a pcap file?I'm really lost here.

Comment: Your current approach to machine learning is similar to giving a child 1000 random books and hope it will somehow learn something from it. It definitely will (like to find out how far it can throw them), but probably not what you expect. So before you start with the learning part you have to find out what you want it to learn. Based on this you  have to define the needed features and only then you can start extracting the features from pcap. And once you know what features you need you can also ask more specific questions.