# How to convert a botnet dataset of PCAP files to ARFF format to be used on Weka?

Tags: networking, weka, pcap, file-conversion, arff

I am trying to convert the dataset contained on https://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/botnet.html to arff format so that I can experiment with it on Weka.

I'm also wondering what attributes should I select to start out my investigations? Thanks.

Comment: PCAP is a capture of the network traffic while ARFF are samples with features. There is no unique conversions between PCAP as ARFF the same there is no conversion between an audio file and ARFF, it depends on what kind of features you are interested in. This can be bytes, flow information, timing behavior, kind of protocols used ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pcap to arff conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685782/pcap-to-arff-conversion). See also https://gist.github.com/PMaynard/144321464085fc7c3c17

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Both are helpful. I suppose a follow up question then is what features would be useful to convert to arff in an attempt to detect botnets?

Comment: What features are usable for detecting botnets would be more on topic at [security.se] instead here. But just asking for this might just result in pointing out that there is lots of published research about this - so please [study existing research](https://www.google.com/search?q=botnet+detection++features+network+traffic) first. It might also be useful to just search for [publications which cite the dataset in question](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?cites=17193268786280672381&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. One last question if it's okay. Have you used the script that you shared from that GitHub link? There doesn't appear to be a ReadMe file with an explanation as to how arguments can be used (i.e. the pcap input file). Sorry for derailing the original question somewhat.

Comment: I did not use this script, just found it when using a search engine. But in my opinion it is pretty obvious from reading the short script what it does, what the limitations are and how to use it.